# opposite of _.where(list, properties)

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of objects and I set `Selected = true` to some customers.
Using `_.where` I'm getting a new array which have only the selected customers.
Is there any method to get the customers who don't have this attribute?
I don't want to set `Selected = false` to the rest of the customers and grab them by

```
_.where(customers, {Selected: false});
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

use `_.reject`

```
_.reject(customers, function(cust) { return cust.Selected; });
```

Docs: http://underscorejs.org/#reject

> Returns the values in list without the elements that the truth test (iterator) passes. The opposite of filter.

Another option if you need this particular logic a lot: You could also create your own Underscore Mixin with: `_.mixin` and create a `_.whereNot` function and keep the nice short syntax of `_.where`

Answer (score 2):

you could do it this way, if you are sure that the property will not be there:

```
_.where(customers, {Selected: undefined});
```

this won't work if the object has `Selected: false`

You could also use `_.filter` which would probably be better:

```
_.filter(customers, function(o) { return !o.Selected; });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It was so simple, I didn't know that you can pass undefined as a parameter. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

I don't there's an opposite exactly, but you could easily just use [`filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter), which lets you specify a function as the predicate (or similarly, `reject`):

```
_.filter(customers, function(customer) { typeof customer.Selected == "undefined" });
```

Similarly if you wanted a list of customers whose `Selected` is undefined *or* false:

```
_.reject(customers, function(customer) { customer.Selected === true });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use .filter method instead

```
_.filter(customers, function(c) {return !c.Selected;});
```